# How to refetch object existing in NSManagedContext

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I created `UIViewController` using an `NSManagedObject` instance, let call it `A`. The `A` has beed fetched from `mainContext`.

In other part of the project some kind of process have updated `NSPersistedContainer` using `backgroundContext`. During this update `A` changed state.

What is the best way to update `UIViewController` from the first paragraph. How to refetch `A` to update existing `NSManagedObject` in `mainContext`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to handle merging changes made on one context into another context is:

1. Add an observer for the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification.
2. When this notification is posted, use `mergeChanges(fromContextDidSave notification: Notification)` to update your context from changes made in the save operation. You can just pass the `Notification` along and the merge will happen, and your object will be refreshed.

An alternative is to use `refresh(_ object: NSManagedObject, mergeChanges flag: Bool)` for your object. Pass `true` for the second argument to merge in changes from the persistent store. This is probably not as good because it only affects a single object instead of everything in the context, but it's useful in some cases.

Comment: That is kind of answer I looking for, thank you. I will try to learn something about `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` notification.

Comment: +1 I agree it is the right way. we used core data a lot on different threads and it was often faster and easier and cleaner to just refetch them into the right context ...

Answer (score 0):

fetch in using NSFetchRequest with the predicate being the objectID! :)

the id is valid accross contextes for existing (saved) objects

Comment: yea I was thinking about this, I looking for method like `object.refresh`, is `NSFetchRequest` giving the best performance in this specific case?

Comment: if you have more than object for sure. if you have just one itll be roughly equivalent to refresh